# Django: get data from tables and display together using ListView

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to display data from 2 tables (and more in the future), but something doesnt work in my code.

my **views.py:**

```
**imports**
def home(request):
    context = {'users': Person.object.all(),
               'emails': Email.object.all()
              }
    return render(request,'app/home.html',context)

class PersonListView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'app/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'users'
```

and in my **home.html**

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for user in users %}
    Displaying user attributes works fine
    {% endfor %}

Here should be emails
{% for email in emails %}
    This displaying doesnt work
{% endfor %}
{% endbock content %}
```

So, displaying users works without any problem, but cant display anything form emails, but if I do it in shell, everything works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) is designed to display only *one* queryset at a time. If you need to pass extra querysets, you can override the [**`get_context_data(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

```
class PersonListView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'app/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'users'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(emails=Email.objects.all())
        return context
```

Here we thus pass an extra variable `emails` to the template rendering engine. Note however that this queryset will not be *paginated* (or at least not without adding some pagination yourself).

> my **`models.py`**:

Note that those are *views*, you need to write these in `views.py`.

Comment: Good to know, thank you again. So, when I will add another table to my context, just shoud use another update?

Comment: @Frendom: you can pass multiple parameters in a single update, like `context.update(foo=Foo.objects.all(), bar=Bar.objects.all(), qux=Qux.objects.all())`.

Comment: let's say that Person is a main model and Email has FK to Person. I don't have problem to display emails who belong to Person in shell, but how should I do in in my views? Or should I do it in my html file?

Comment: @Frendom: you can make a loop in the `{% for person in persons %}` loop with `{% from email in person.email_set %} ... {% endfor %}`. In that in case in the `views.py`, you better perform a `.prefetch_related` however to optimize efficiency.

Comment: I tried something like that: {% for user in user %} {{ user.attr }} and {{ user.email_set }}, but I only get app.Email None. I have __str__ in my models and wonder why it can't be displayed. Is ok if I ask here or should I run new question?

Comment: @Frendom: well here it should look like `{% for person in persons %} {% for email in person.email_set.all %} {{ email }} {% endfor %} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: it doesn't work correctly. I will run new topic and give you an info

Comment: @Frendom: can you please include the *relevant* models?

Comment: I added new question